# center images vertically in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Each image has a div parent, these parents' width and height are in proportion, the question is, i can't center each image inside its parent horizontally. it seems it only takes the first element's height and applies it to the rest of the elements. ![it seems it only takes the first elements height and apply it to all of the rest ][1]

```
function centerImages(image) {
  var parent_height = $('.thumb img').parent().height();  
  var image_height = $('.thumb img').height();  
  var top_margin = (parent_height - image_height) / 2;  
  $('.thumb img').css( 'margin-top' , top_margin);
}

$(".thumb img").each(function() {
        centerImages(this);
});
```

demo: http://codepen.io/waveiron/pen/ExpLd

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a div in a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: I don't think so, this is more related to the use of each() in jQuery, the former on CSS rules

Comment: i've searched all over the world...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pointing to the same image all over again. Simply change to:

```
     function centerImages(image) {
    var parent_height = $(image).parent().height();  
    var image_height = $(image).height();  
    var top_margin = (parent_height - image_height) / 2;  
    $(image).css( 'margin-top' , top_margin);
}
$(".thumb img").each(function() {
    centerImages(this);
});
```

Plus add 'px' as also suggested.

Comment: @Kevin please mark this answer as correct (the little V on the left side)

Comment: oh! there is a 'V', i never noticed.. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing to add `px`:

```
$('.thumb img').css( 'margin-top' , top_margin + "px");
```

(I'd also suggest to cache jQuery objects when possible:

```
var $image = $(image);
var parent_height = $image.parent().height();
var image_height = $image.height();
```

)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use an inline-block helper with height: 100% and vertical-align: middle on both elements.

Or, if you don't want to have an extra element in modern browsers and don't mind using IE expressions, you can use a pseudo-element and add it to IE using a convenient Expression, that runs only once per element, so there won't be any perfomance issues

If I understod your question right....